# How to logout from youtube service?

Tags: c#, youtube-api

I'm using this code to do the stuff, but i don't know how we can logout from it and login from another account.

```
UserCredential credential;
using (var stream = GenerateStreamFromString(secret))
{
    credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
        GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
        // This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows for read-only access to the authenticated 
        // user's account, but not other types of account access.
        new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube, YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeForceSsl, YouTubeService.Scope.Youtubepartner, YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload },
        email,
        CancellationToken.None,
        new FileDataStore(this.GetType().ToString())
    );
}

string accToken = credential.Token.AccessToken;


youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = this.GetType().ToString()
});
```

Comment: I think there is no "logout". Logout means : close or dispose all your connection and forget all variable. Then you can do it all over again using another username. Just like in browser, if you delete all your cookies, you are logged out.

Comment: Yup you are right. Just sent a request to this url and was logged out. `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token=accToken` Add your comment as answer i will accept it. Thanks